# How do I make my speech_recognition pause threshold work correctly

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am trying to take audio input and save it as .wav file.
My code is the following:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
def save():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    r.pause_threshold = 0.6
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Yes')
        
        audio=r.listen(source)
    with open('test.wav','wb') as wav:
         wav.write(audio.get_wav_data())
save()
```

If I save and run this file it listens forever or till I terminate the code.
Can anybody help me.
Thank you
-***Levers***

Comment: This code runs fine for me. It records the wav file for as long as I set the pause_threshold. What am I missing here?

Comment: It was wrong on my side speech recognition module was not working

Answer (score 0):

```
import speech_recognition as sr
def save():
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    r.pause_threshold = 0.6
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Yes')
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio=r.listen(source)
    with open('test.wav','wb') as wav:
         wav.write(audio.get_wav_data())
save()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hello It is happening because the energy threshold is very lower for your environment and your microphone.
Try using: `r.energy_threshold = 600`

> You can increase and decrease the value as it's vary from microphon to microphone or environment.